# Hide or disallow certain users to access modern SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I was asked to restrict access for two users on a new SharePoint site, and it seems that there is no option to do that easily. Does anyone know how to go about this?

All I'm able to see under "SharePoint Site Permissions" is:

- Site owner
- Site member
- Site visitor

Even in advanced settings, it seems that one can only add permission, not remove or restrict.

I've seen other threads how some people fixed it but, most of them are on SharePoint 2013 or older.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In order to restrict users from accessing whole SharePoint site, you need to remove user permissions. To remove user from group firstly you should have proper permissions on site and that particular group.

Comment: So there is no way to explicitly set two users to not be able to see a SharePoint site?

I still want them to belong in the "all user except external users" group without having to restructure all permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove users from a group.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions

If you set "all user except external users" group permission on the site, then the two users(if they are not external users) will have permission on the site.